# IOS 13 Get Wifi and Cellular Network Signal Strength

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I have tried all the possible way of getting the wifi and cellular network signal strength.

```
    func getSignalStrength() -> Int {
        let application = UIApplication.shared
       //let statusBarView = application.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
        let statusBarView = UIApplication.shared.statusBarUIView
        let foregroundView = statusBarView?.value(forKey: "foregroundView") as! UIView
        let foregroundViewSubviews = foregroundView.subviews

        var dataNetworkItemView:UIView!

        for subview in foregroundViewSubviews {
            if subview.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView")!) {
                dataNetworkItemView = subview
                print("NONE")
                break
            } else {
                print("NONE")

                return 0 //NO SERVICE
            }
        }

        return dataNetworkItemView.value(forKey: "signalStrengthBars") as! Int
    }

    private func wifiStrength() -> Int? {
        let app = UIApplication.shared
        var rssi: Int?
        guard let statusBar = app.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView, let foregroundView = statusBar.value(forKey: "foregroundView") as? UIView else {
            return rssi
        }
        for view in foregroundView.subviews {
            if let statusBarDataNetworkItemView = NSClassFromString("UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView"), view .isKind(of: statusBarDataNetworkItemView) {
                if let val = view.value(forKey: "wifiStrengthRaw") as? Int {
                    //print("rssi: \(val)")

                    rssi = val
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        return rssi
    }


extension UIApplication {
var statusBarUIView: UIView? {

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let tag = 38482458

        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
            .compactMap({$0})
            .first?.windows.first

        if let statusBar = keyWindow?.viewWithTag(tag) {
            return statusBar
        } else {

            let statusBarView = UIView(frame: (keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager!.statusBarFrame)!)
            statusBarView.tag = tag
            statusBarView.layer.zPosition = 999999

            keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBarView)
            return statusBarView
        }

    } else {

        if responds(to: Selector(("statusBar"))) {
            return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
        }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

the code crashed at application.value(forKey: "statusBar") so I tried the extension but now it crashed at statusBarView?.value(forKey: "foregroundView"), no key pair value for foregroundView. Is there a better to get wifi or cellular signal?

Answer (score 2):

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        if let statusBarManager = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager,
            let localStatusBar = statusBarManager.value(forKey: "createLocalStatusBar") as? NSObject,
            let statusBar = localStatusBar.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? NSObject,
            let _statusBar = statusBar.value(forKey: "_statusBar") as? UIView,
            let currentData = _statusBar.value(forKey: "currentData")  as? NSObject,
            let celluar = currentData.value(forKey: "cellularEntry") as? NSObject,
            let signalStrength = celluar.value(forKey: "displayValue") as? Int {
            return signalStrength
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    } else {
        var signalStrength = -1
        let application = UIApplication.shared
        let statusBarView = application.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
        let foregroundView = statusBarView.value(forKey: "foregroundView") as! UIView
        let foregroundViewSubviews = foregroundView.subviews
        var dataNetworkItemView: UIView!
        for subview in foregroundViewSubviews {
            if subview.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView")!) {
                dataNetworkItemView = subview
                break
            } else {
                signalStrength = -1
            }
        }
        signalStrength = dataNetworkItemView.value(forKey: "signalStrengthBars") as! Int
        if signalStrength == -1 {
            return nil
        } else {
            return signalStrength
        }
    }
    return nil
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: how to get wifi signal strenght?